# Not able to mention usernames on Android Stack Exchange app

Tags: support, bug, android-app

I'm using the Stack Exchange app on my Android device and when I try to mention someone in the comments it's not showing the auto complete and the users are not getting mentioned. Can anyone help me on this issue?

Comment: @PSN click on the left arrow on the top menu after tapping the comment you want to reply to. Just did it from the app...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Auto-complete to reply doesn't work in the Android app, but you can reply to a comment by selecting the comment (tap on it) and then from the top menu bar that appears select the left arrow button, like in the screenshot below:

[image: Show where to click to reply to comment.]

After selecting the arrow, the comment box is activated, with `@username` already completed.

Comment: Its working for the answer but not my question.

Comment: @PSN: I am bit confused by your comment... Are you saying that the reply shortcut doesn't work on a specific question? Or that the answer missed the point of this meta question?

Comment: I mean its working when I do the above steps in this answer section but when I click on the comment button below my question I can't see the arrow.

Comment: @PSN That's weird. Are you sure the comment you selected to reply to is not your own? You won't get the link in that case.

Comment: Yes I'm sure. I tried Peter Mortensen's comment.

Comment: @PSN Another thing I just noticed is that if you started to type the comment the link doesn't appear. It is only there if the comment textfield is closed.